# What do you call this two-wheeled vehicle?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Somebody call it a "caboose". But I looked it up in the dictionary in which it states:

> the part at the back of a train where the person who is in charge of the train rides

It's seems not a correct usage to refer to the two-wheeled vehicle in the upper image. What do you guys call it? Thanks.

Comment: You would accurately refer to this as a "thing," rather than "stuff". "Stuff" is an uncountable noun, and implies a collection of items rather than just one, whereas a thing is one item.

Comment: what exactly is this item used for? Carrying cargo or people? Look up "rickshaw" or "pulled rickshaw," does that fit at all?

Comment: I guess you could call it a rickshaw or a cart or a wheelbarrow, but it does depend on what it's for.

Comment: @Esther You can use it to hold things while you are hiking.

Comment: I would call it a 'hand rickshaw' provided that it is intended to be pulled by a person.

Comment: I find "hand rickshaw" odd, since traditionally, all rickshaws are pulled by hand, and are usually used for people, not cargo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is **[handcart](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/handcart)**:

> A handcart is a small cart with two wheels which is pushed or pulled along and is used for transporting goods.

Yours is small, has two wheels, is pushed or pulled by a human, and is used for transporting things, so the word seems appropriate.